# SOQL to get Assets with AccountId different from Parent.AccountId

Tags: soql, childrelationship, child-to-parent, parent, asset

I need to get all Assets X with X.ParentId != NULL, and the X.Parent.AccountId != X.AccountId.

```
SELECT AccountId,Id,ParentId,Parent.AccountId,RecordTypeId,RootAssetId FROM Asset WHERE ParentId != NULL AND Parent.AccountId != AccountId AND RecordType.DeveloperName='RecTypeABC' limit 10
```

The SOQL above fails with a `MALFORMED_QUERY` error.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a field to field comparison in `SOQL` i.e. as mentioned in the question, you cannot compare `X.Parent.AccountId != X.AccountId`.

There is other workaround by which you can do this i.e. by creating a new formula field which evaluates to `true` when `X.Parent.AccountId = X.AccountId` and `false` when it is not same.

The formula for your new field would be

```
IF(X.Parent.AccountId = X.AccountId, 'true', 'false')
```

And then you can query for records where this new formula field is 'false'

So your query would become

```
SELECT AccountId,Id,ParentId,Parent.AccountId,RecordTypeId,RootAssetId FROM Asset WHERE ParentId != NULL AND New_Formula_Field__c='false' AND RecordType.DeveloperName='RecTypeABC' limit 10
```

You can refer [Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331053&type=1&mode=1) for further help on this topic.